# PID of a nested command in a subshell

Tags: bash, process, macos, subshell

Okay, I've got a program I'm trying to fix, for lengthy reasons a rewrite isn't the greatest option... So, I've been up for 8 hours trying to solve this and I'm completely stumped.

I'm trying to get the PID of the ffmpeg in this nested subshell command:

`(touch ~/addThumSlate.1BUSY.FILE; echo "" | ffmpeg -I "~/thumb_0011374_402.mov" "~/0011374/402_slated.mxv" > "~/0011374_402-addThumSlate1.txt" 2>&1; rm -f ~/addThumSlate1.BUSY.FILE) >/dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!`

Obviously the final " & echo $!" does not return the pid of the ffmpeg command, and "echo $!" doesn't work within a subshell, and I tried messing around with `echo $$; ( : ; bash -c 'echo $PPID' )` but that was only retuning me the parent shell for some reason?

Caveat, this is bash 3.2 running on a Mac, so `$BASHPID` is out. Also, I can't `ps | grep 'ffmpeg'`, as there are multiple ffmpegs running. I've trolled the interwebs trying to find a solution.

Hoping you can help,

```
 -Sleepless in a subshell
```

Comment: foo could be replaced with `sh -c 'echo $$ > /some/pidfile; exec foo'`

Answer (score 0):

$! should be the pid of the subshell. Try `pstree -p $!` to see if the information you need is in the list.

You may need to parse it (maybe in awk), and the output to a pipe is different to what you see on screen.

Example from my login shell. You should see one ffmpeg in your list.

```
paul $ pstree -p $PPID | cat -vet
mate-terminal(6849)-+-bash(6856)---vi(9107)$
                    |-bash(7338)$
                    |-bash(9456)-+-cat(10573)$
                    |            `-pstree(10572)$
                    |-{dconf worker}(6855)$
                    |-{gdbus}(6854)$
                    `-{gmain}(6852)$
paul $
```

You may need to download pstree from the Mac Store: http://macappstore.org/pstree/

Typical awk ending to store the Pid in a variable would be:

```
Pid=$( pstree -p $PPID | awk -v 'RS=)' -v 'FS=(' '/ffmpeg/ { print $NF }' )
```